# How does .Where in LINQ actually work under the hood?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

In the book "C# in a Nutshell" by Joseph Albahari, it's said that .Where is implemented like below:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        if (predicate (element))
            yield return element;
}
```

But to me it looks like using "foreach" here will enumerate our collection, so in a case when we have collection.Where(x => ...).Where(x => ...).ToList() - enumeration will happen 3 times: 1st time in the 1st Where, 2nd time in the 2nd Where, and at last in ToList(). But I was thinking, that the whole idea of LINQ chains is to enumerate it only once.
Am I mistaken and it will be enumerated only once? Please guide me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it looks like using "foreach" here will enumerate our collection,

It does *look like* that, but it's not what actually happens. Instead, the `yield` keyword tells the compiler it should perform a [**transformation**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gHVYnv) on the method so it creates an `IEnumerator` object that only *knows how* to iterate the collection, without actually doing that work right away. No enumeration happens at all until you actually use and iterate through this created object.

The compiler transformation happens in such a way as to be *stackable*, so even with multiple calls to `.Where()`, as in the `collection.Where(x => ...).Where(x => ...).ToList()` expression in the question, **only one enumeration** takes place. You can mix in other linq operations like `.Select()`, `.Any()`, `.Aggregate()`, etc, as well.

Therefore, in the question's sample code, the only enumeration happens as part of the final call to `.ToList()`.

This can make composing linq code *extremely efficient*. The downside is each use of this results in a memory allocation for the enumeration object, so it's useful to be aware when you are memory-constrained vs cpu-constrained (*and don't neglect the GC cost of the allocations*). Often it's worthwhile to combine some of these, so `.Where(x => ...).Where(x => ...)` instead becomes `.Where(x => ... && ...)`. I'm still hopeful the C# team will come up with some magic "ValueEnumerable", as they've done for tuples and task and spans, that can reduce these allocations.

Finally, while there are exceptions to this, generally you should **avoid calling `ToList()`** (or `ToArray()`) as much as possible. Instead, prefer `IEnumerable<T>` over `List<T>` or `T[]` for method arguments, return types, and variable declarations. In many cases, it's enough for the final `foreach` loop, data binding, or other mechanism to force the final enumeration, such that you don't actually need to construct a list or array, and these other options are **way more efficient** than actually building (and allocating memory for) a list that may not be needed, especially for sequences where the final size cannot be inferred up front and are large enough to hit `List<T>`'s doubling algorithm multiple times.